# Write keyEvent for Next key in Android keyboard?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have a ListView with EditText and I wrote onEditorAction Listner in my adapter class for Next key of Android keyboard to my calculation . I wrote that listner it works fine for me but after it's done with my calculation it's not going to focus on next EditText inside my listview before writing this OnEditorAction it focuses on the next edittext in listview . 
How can I achieve this so it solves my problem?

Here is the code:

```
ed_Current.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            int tag = (Integer) v.getTag();

            if((actionId== EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT)){
                Log.i("tag","lostFocus");
                Some calculation then go to next edittext


                return true;
            }


            return false;
        }
    });
```